# How to change the administrative borders for Crimea

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap

How can make changes to display Crimea as part of Ukraine. For leaflet I can't find anything like it

Comment: Have you found something that works without leaflet, then? When asking, it's usually a good idea to write about any previous research done on the subject.

Comment: In Leaflet you can't really change how the map looks except if you switch to a different tile source. So either find a tile server that displays a different border or a tile server that doesn't render any borders at all. In the latter case you can add an overlay with your own borders.